# Firebase - can I enforce an action to take place after reading particular data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I am using Firebase and want to forcefully delete a message after a user has read it. How can I enforce such a rule in Firebase? I am looking for ways to force actions to occur (deleting something or incrementing something) after data read at particular data-points.

The problem with forcing this using client-side API is that that could be easily surpassed by modifying the client-level code. So, I need to implement this as a Firebase rule.

Comment: you could manage your rules in a way that only a server side application will have access to it.Then you can enforce that the users will only be able to see your data calling this server and whenever a user read the data it gets deleted or something.

Comment: I was really looking for a way to do this using firebase rules, without using an external server